# Python shows name error for a dictionary that exists

Tags: python, dictionary

For my school project, im making a library management system, in which the book ID assigned to a student should be there in the keys of another dictionary, bkd(which stores book details and the keys are the book IDs).
The student records are in a file library.dat and the book records are in a file bookrec.dat
The student records are in form of a dictionary(rec) and book details are in dictionary(bkd)
Now, when i try to use an if statement to check whether the book id entered by a user is there in bkd.keys(), the program gives a name error. Any solutions?

```
def crt_lib_rec():
    g=open('bookrec.dat','rb')
    f=open('library.dat','ab')
    rec={}
    rno=int(input('Enter Rno: '))
    nm=input('Enter name: ')
    gd=int(input("Enter the Grade of the student: "))
    div=input("Enter the Class of the student: ")
    bookid=int(input("Enter the Book ID: "))
    retdate=input("Enter the date of return: ")
    if bookid in bkd.keys():
        rec[rno]={'Name':nm,'Grade':gd,'Division':div,'Book ID':bookid,'Return Date':retdate}
        p.dump(rec,f)
        print("Record Created Successfully..")
    else:
        print("Enter a valid Book ID..")
```

The dictionary bkd is created in another function crtbookrec()

Here is crtbookrec:

```
def crt_book_rec():
    g=open('bookrec.dat','ab')
    bkd={}
    bkid=int(input('Enter Book ID: '))
    bknme=input('Enter Book Name: ')
    authnme=input("Enter Author Name: ")
    bkd[bkid]={'Book Name':bknme,'Author Name':authnme}
    p.dump(bkd,g)
    g.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 410, in <module>
    menufn()
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 350, in menufn
    crtlibrec()
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 19, in crtlibrec
    if bookid in bkd.keys():
NameError: name 'bkd' is not defined
```

Menu that calls the functions:

```
def menufn():
    menu1='1.Student Details\n2.Book Details\n3.Exit'
    while True:
        print('='*90)
        print("\n\t\t\t    ABC Public School\n\n\t\t\t     Kottayam,Kerala\n\n\t\t\t    LIBRARY MANAGEMENT\n")
        print('='*90)
        print(menu1)
        print('='*90)
        opt1=input("Enter your choice(1/2/3): ")
        if opt1=='1':
            menu2='1.Create Student Record\n2.Display Student Records\n3.Modify Student Records\n4.Modify Book Issued\n5.Modify Return Date\n6.Search Student Records\n7.Delete Student Record\n8.Exit The Program'
            ch2='y'
            while True:
                print('='*90)
                print("\n\t\t\tSTUDENT DETAILS PROGRAM\n")
                print(menu2,"\n")
                print('='*90)
                opt2=input('Enter your choice: ')
                if opt2=='1':
                    #crtlibrec is called here
                    print('-'*10,'Creating Record','-'*10)
                    crt_lib_rec(bkd)
                elif opt2=='2':
                    print('-'*10,'Displaying Records','-'*10)
                    display_studet()
                elif opt2=='3':
                    print('-'*10,'Modifying Student Records','-'*10)
                    modify_stdet()
                elif opt2=='4':
                    print('-'*10,'Modifying Book Issued','-'*10)
                    modify_book_issd()
                elif opt2=='5':
                    print('-'*10,'Modifying Return Date','-'*10)
                    modify_ret_date()
                elif opt2=='6':
                    print('-'*10,'Searching Records','-'*10)
                    Search_stud()
                elif opt2=='7':
                    print('-'*10,'Deleting Student Record','-'*10)
                    Delete_std_rec()
                
                elif opt2=='8':
                    print('Exiting....')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Enter valid input')
                
        elif opt1=="2":
            menu3='1.Create Book Record\n2.Display Book Record\n3.Modify Book Records\n4.Search Book Records\n5.Delete Book Record\n6.Exit The Program'
            
            while True:
                print('='*90)
                print("\n\t\t\tBOOK DETAILS PROGRAM\n")
                print(menu3)
                print('='*90)
                opt3=input('Enter your choice: ')
                if opt3=='1':
                    #crtbookrec is called here
                    print('-'*10,'Creating Book Record','-'*10)
                    crt_book_rec()
                elif opt3=='2':
                    print('-'*10,'Displaying Book Records','-'*10)
                    display_book_rec()
                elif opt3=='3':
                    print('-'*10,'Modifying Book Records','-'*10)
                    modify_book_rec()
                elif opt3=='4':
                    print('-'*10,'Searching Book Records','-'*10)
                    search_book_rec()
                elif opt3=='5':
                    print('-'*10,'Deleting Book Record','-'*10)
                    delete_book_rec()
                elif opt3=='6':
                    print('Exiting....')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Enter valid input')
        elif opt1=="3":
            print("Thank You for using the Library Management Program")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice..")
menufn()
```

im sorry if the code is badly commented or written, im new to python

Comment: You have to pass `bkd` as a parameter.

Comment: share full eror details please.

Comment: `bkd` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: @balderman Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 410, in <module>
    menufn()
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 350, in menufn
    crtlibrec()
  File "C:\Users\kesha\Desktop\Project\Proj copy for testing\proj test.py", line 19, in crtlibrec
    if bookid in bkd.keys():
NameError: name 'bkd' is not defined

Comment: @RobinGertenbach bkd is defined in another function, crtbookrec, which is used to create book records, is the variable local to the function, and if so how do i make it accessible to the main program?

Comment: Edit the question and put the traceback there - as a code block for easier reading.

Comment: Two options: 1) pass bkd as argument to the function 2) declare bkd as global. Add the `Traceback` to the post body.

Comment: Not really related but you can improve function names: `crtbookrec` --> `crt_book_rec` (as an example)

Comment: @balderman i tried global bkd, let me try passing bkd as argument
also, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Share the caller of the 2 functions as well. Make `crtbookrec ` return `bkd`

Comment: @balderman i tried to pass crtlibrec(bkd) and return bkd but there is still bkd is not defined. global bkd also isnt working

Comment: 1) rename the 2 functions 2) share the main logic that is calling both functions.

Comment: the full code is around 400 lines, so the caller would have a huge menu. ill edit it in the question anyways

Comment: @KeshavNair I have posted an answer that shows how the *skeleton*  of the code should look like. Go with this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code **skeleton** should look like the below

```
def crtlibrec(bkd):
    # do something with bkd

def crtbookrec():
  return bkd

def main():
  bkd = crtbookrec()
  crtlibrec(bkd)
```